# Paypal Subscription with Initial Payment

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am working with a customer to setup a paypal button to allow them to charge a customer an initial setup fee and then a monthly subscription.  I am rather new to this, so I am looking for the best way to do this as I didn't see anything that seemed to stick out in the documentation on developer.paypal.com for this scenario.  Do I use the restful api or classic api?  The site is built in .Net, so if you also have any information to this as well, that would be appreciated.  Now I am not looking for code, but just a nudge in the right direction so I can find out all the information I need to do this right. Thanks.

Wade

Comment: If you're going to down vote me, please do me the favor of saying why.  How will I ever improve if no one ever says anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Payments Standard Subscription button for this. They're pretty simple to create and add to the site. They can be created through a PayPal account or from your own custom HTML form.

The PayPal button code is just a an HTML form so you shouldn't have a problem adding it to your customer's site. Here are some details on Subscription buttons:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/

I wouldn't recommend using an API but if you want to learn more about them you can look around on Developer.PayPal.com

Comment: I did find the subscription button, but it didn't seem to offer the ability to get an initial payment and then schedule monthly payments.

Comment: It does allow for an initial payment through the setup of a trial period using the a1, p1, and t1 variables. The a3, p3, and t3 variables set the schedule for regular monthly payments.

Comment: The only confusing part was the fact that I could only set the trial period to 1 day, but the customer wants immediate payment.  So am I just reading it wrong?  Is the customer paying immediately for the trial period (even if it could be free) and after the trial period the billing starts?  Thanks for the help so far as I haven't seen a document explaining this.

Comment: The trial period has to be a day at least. The amount to bill for the trial period would happen that day and the following day they would be billed for the start of the regular subscription period.

Comment: Ok, thanks that makes sense.  One last question that the customer just reminded me of today.  The trial payment is the setup fee and the 1st month subscription.  Now I know I can set different subscriptions, but is there a way to make three different trial fees to match the subscription plan?  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I know its old, but if anyone finds this through Google (like I did) this page will help: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU

Comment: Unfortunately the Trial period will only work if you have only 1 subscription choice, i.e. Trial = Setup + 1st Month, then a Monthly fee after. In my case, I want to offer an Annual fee (a discount compared to Monthly), but only 1 Trial option is possible, so an Annual subscriber would then be charged Trial (Setup + 1st Month) and billed Annually thereafter.